# How to extend panel data to balanced panel data on three dimensions in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, panel

I want to extend panel data to balanced panel data on three dimensions. Below is an example:

This is the original dataframe:

| city | Type | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New York | A | 1993 |
| New York | B | 1994 |
| New York | B | 1995 |
| Los Angeles | A | 1992 |
| Los Angeles | B | 1997 |
| Chicago | C | 1996 |

This is what I want:Every city should have all the Type and Year presented in the dataframe. Below is what I want:

| city | Type | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New York | A | 1992 |
| New York | A | 1993 |
| New York | A | 1994 |
| New York | A | 1995 |
| New York | A | 1996 |
| New York | A | 1997 |
| New York | B | 1992 |
| New York | B | 1993 |
| New York | B | 1994 |
| New York | B | 1995 |
| New York | B | 1996 |
| New York | B | 1997 |
| New York | C | 1992 |
| New York | C | 1993 |
| New York | C | 1994 |
| New York | C | 1995 |
| New York | C | 1996 |
| New York | C | 1997 |
| Los Angeles | A | 1992 |
| Los Angeles | A | 1993 |
| Los Angeles | A | 1994 |
| Los Angeles | A | 1995 |
| Los Angeles | A | 1996 |
| Los Angeles | A | 1997 |
| Los Angeles | B | 1992 |
| Los Angeles | B | 1993 |
| Los Angeles | B | 1994 |
| Los Angeles | B | 1995 |
| Los Angeles | B | 1996 |
| Los Angeles | B | 1997 |
| Los Angeles | C | 1992 |
| Los Angeles | C | 1993 |
| Los Angeles | C | 1994 |
| Los Angeles | C | 1995 |
| Los Angeles | C | 1996 |
| Los Angeles | C | 1997 |
| Chicago | A | 1992 |
| Chicago | A | 1993 |
| Chicago | A | 1994 |
| Chicago | A | 1995 |
| Chicago | A | 1996 |
| Chicago | A | 1997 |
| Chicago | B | 1992 |
| Chicago | B | 1993 |
| Chicago | B | 1994 |
| Chicago | B | 1995 |
| Chicago | B | 1996 |
| Chicago | B | 1997 |
| Chicago | C | 1992 |
| Chicago | C | 1993 |
| Chicago | C | 1994 |
| Chicago | C | 1995 |
| Chicago | C | 1996 |
| Chicago | C | 1997 |

I wonder how to solve this problem in Python? Thanks a lot for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this. Set the input iterables to unique (sorted) list-likes of your columns.

```
from itertools import product
df_new = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df.city.unique(), 
                                   sorted(df.Type.unique()), 
                                   sorted(df.Year.unique())
                                   )), 
                      columns=df.columns)

print(df_new.loc[df_new.city == 'New York'])

        city Type  Year
0   New York    A  1992
1   New York    A  1993
2   New York    A  1994
3   New York    A  1995
4   New York    A  1996
5   New York    A  1997
6   New York    B  1992
7   New York    B  1993
8   New York    B  1994
9   New York    B  1995
10  New York    B  1996
11  New York    B  1997
12  New York    C  1992
13  New York    C  1993
14  New York    C  1994
15  New York    C  1995
16  New York    C  1996
17  New York    C  1997
```